# File Transfer Protocol using TCP

Tags: sockets, tcp, ftp, network-programming

im a university student and I've been tasked with creating a simple File Transfer Protocol using TCP between two machines.
I have very basic knowledge about sockets, and I've been using Linux for a bit. Is it possible to create two virtual machines on VirtualBox (linux machines) and have one be the server and the other be the client? Is that the right way to go about it?

Another question I have is for protocol specification. Is this something I specify in the client or server program or in a separate program?

Other than that, I would appreciate any useful resources or examples you can provide me as a starting point, as it's taking me a lot longer than I thought to really understand how to accomplish this through resources I currrently have. I apologize to any of you who feel this is an unproductive post but I am simply seeking any advice I can get from you more experienced programmers out there.

Thanks!

Comment: You can use two virtual machines but you don't need to. Server and client can run in the same host, at least for testing purposes. The protocol specification is a document, not part of a program.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to create two virtual machines on VirtualBox (linux
> machines) and have one be the server and the other be the client? Is
> that the right way to go about it?

You can do that, but to start with you might find it simpler to run the client and server programs both on the same host.  There is no requirement that they must run on separate machines (virtual or otherwise).

> Another question I have is for protocol specification. Is this
> something I specify in the client or server program or in a separate
> program?

The protocol specification is part of the documentation; it's not part of either program.  Both programs will have to follow the specification in order to interoperate with each other properly, of course.

> Other than that, I would appreciate any useful resources or examples you can provide me as a starting point,

Pointers to resources/examples are off-topic for StackOverflow, but you can google e.g. "TCP programming tutorial" or "TCP programming FAQ" or similar and you should find lots of content.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your help. I just found a bunch of tutorials on YouTube which I didn't even consider looking for before. Also appreciate you clarifying my doubts for the protocol specification question and the client/host question